# Can't change recoveryaneblad to No in BCDEdit

Tags: windows-10, bcdedit

I managed to get into an automatic repair loop on my Win 10 machine.

After a couple of repair options I try to disable to recovery in bcdedit.
I run different variations of the following code:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
bcdedit /set {current} recoveryenabled No
bcdedit /set bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailure no
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailure no
etc.
```

After each of these I tried to check if the value changed with this code

```
bcdedit
```

But recoveryanbled is always YES.

I also noticed that I have to type in `<` and `>` instead of `{` `}` is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

bcdedit operates on system BCD if parameter /store not specified.

System BCD is on active partition of boot device (can be hard disk, USB, DVD ...).

On UEFI boot System BCD is on EFI System Partition (ESP) of boot device.

The notation {default} or {current} is fixed and specifies the "default" loader or "current" loader object.

You should be more specific about how you reach command prompt.
Do you use a recovery USB?
Is Windows version (bit version) on USB the same as on hard disk?
Do you use recovery console from installed OS?

Alternatively try using [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) which gives full access to BCD be it system BCD or another BCD anywhere on any accessible device.

Comment: I solved the problem but I don't really remember how (sorry, it's already been months now...).
Thanks anyway for the help :)